# Visual Studio Code URL Highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently in Visual Studio Code all URL's are highlighted with an underline, and this underline is actionable with a Ctrl + Click.

Is it possible to turn this URL highlighting feature off?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: sorry, I think you question is off topic on SO

Answer (score 3):

Try the `editor.links` setting in [`settings.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings):

```js
// Controls whether the editor should detect links and make them clickable
"editor.links": true,
```

[image: With "editor.links": true]

```js
// Controls whether the editor should detect links and make them clickable
"editor.links": false,
```

[image]

Comment: I'd like to keep links clickable and just get rid of the underlines. Is it possible?

Comment: @Betty have you figured it out by any chance?

Comment: Seems like yes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40918600/getting-rid-of-underline-link/69555779#69555779