# Getting rid of underline (link)

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I get rid of this underline? When I hover over it, it thinks it's a link and that I can `cmd + click` it to open it in browser. However, it's obstructing the view of actual underlines.

I'm specifically using Go's templating engine and vscode's basic HTML syntax because it's not supported.

[image]

Comment: Does it also do that outside of the `href` attribute of the `a` tag? It seems a setting in your IDE for anchor tags.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Nope, you can see the `{{ .Title }}` from the above image.

Comment: Refer to the vscode manual then to find where this setting is set.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I actually looked around before asking this question, including the settings file. To make sure, I browsed again but no luck.

Comment: They would have implemented it but because less than 20 people voted for it, they didn't. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/140657 Pretty stupid policy to hold a vote for 60 days on a feature request as how would all the interested people in the world know that a vote is taking place right now and they now have to vote for it?

Answer (score 11):

I think I found a solution for your problem. 
Add this code to your **User Settings**;

```
"editor.links": false
```

Comment: I'd like to keep links clickable and just get rid of the underlines. Is it possible?

Comment: wondering the same, @Betty :(

Comment: @katerlouis I later found a way. See my answer.

Comment: User asked for getting rid of the underline, not about  getting rid of the link.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep links clickable and just get rid of the underlines, I found a way:

open `resources\app\out\vs\workbench\workbench.desktop.main.css`

search for `.monaco-editor .detected-link,` and delete it.

Reopen VSCode, it will show some warning. Allow it and it's done.

After every update, you'll need to edit this file again.

Comment: Is monaco the theme? Do you know where this css file is for other themes like Material Theme on macOS?

Comment: @katerlouis I think Monaco is the editor that powers VS Code under the hood. (https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) This method works regardless of the theme for me on Windows. I don't own a Mac but I guess it's the same, since VSC is based on Electron.