# How to remove an embedded hyperlink in Visual Studio Code

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code

I have a csv file I am working with in Visual Studio Code(VSC). The file contains several hyperlinks attached to text in the document. For example:

```
Available at SSRN: [https://ssrn.com/abstract=3261275][1]
```

I want to remove these hyperlinks. I checked the [basic editing documents](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) for Visual Studio Code. However, they provide no guidance on how to edit text in Visual Studio Code. Rather, the only available information is on editing text in VSC is how to develop or use keyboard shortcuts. And, after looking through all off the [keyboard shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference) - I have not been able to find a command to remove a hyperlink or clear text formatting.

If this were a word document I could simply right-click and select remove hyperlink or select the clear formatting icon. However, I have been unable to discover how to perform this function in VSC.

How do I remove a hyperlink from text in CSV file in Visual Studio Code?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code URL Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796520/visual-studio-code-url-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

> // Controls whether the editor should detect links and make them
>   clickable.

```
 "editor.links": true,
```

That is the default, set it to `false` in your settings.json.

If you want to set it to false for certain filetypes only, you would use something like:

```
"[plaintext]": {      
   "editor.links": false,
},
```