# How to disable underlining in HTML code that Visual Studio Code does in URLs?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When writing html code and writing URLs the editor shows them with an underline and I don't like to see underlines in the code.
(it's not about the underline in the web browser but I'm talking about the underline in Visual Studio Code)
There should be the option to disable that underline

[image: Example of underlined text in vscode]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code URL Highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796520/visual-studio-code-url-highlighting)

Answer (score 2):

Click `Ctrl + ,` to go to settings and then type `editor.links` in settings search. You should see something like that:
[image]

All you have to do is just uncheck this option and vscode won't underline links anymore.

Comment: Thank you.
Your answer helped me.

Comment: @4Juan check it out: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Answer (score 1):

To disable underlining urls

1st: open file and look for **Preferences**>**Settings**.

2nd: Type in search settings: **editor.links** and just uncheck to disable underlining

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
Your answer helped me.

Comment: Welcome, Always my friend.